# rails 4 not using digests in asset filenames, but only in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, sprockets

I have a Rails 4 app that was recently heavily upgraded (in terms of gem versions and some other things). Deploys have been working fine, but once we cleared out our tmp directories we noticed that assets stopped working in production. What's happening is for some reason in production mode, the helpers aren't using digests in any of the asset filenames (e.g. `/javascripts/application.js` instead of `/javascripts/application-some-digest.js`). This causes those assets to 404, since they do exist with their proper digest names in the `public` directory and Google App Engine is set up to independently serve static files for the public directory (which has always worked fine). What is really strange, though, is that in staging mode, the app is doing everything properly, so there is something about our production environment that is making the helpers not use digests.

Even weirder, though, is if I go `RAILS_ENV=production rails console` and do `helper.asset_path 'application.js'` I get the proper filename with the digest. What on earth could be going on?

And yes, we are doing `RAILS_ENV=production rake:assets:precompile` before deploying.

Here are the relevant parts from `config/environments/production.rb`:

```
  config.eager_load = true
  config.assets.cache_store = :dalli_store
  # Don't force SSL because we need non-ssl cookies.
  config.force_ssl = false
  config.stripe_livemode = true
  config.assets.digest = true
  config.assets.compile = false
```

Here are the relevant parts from `config/environments/shared.rb`:

```
  # Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will already do this)
  config.serve_static_files = false

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS
  config.assets.compress = true

  # Don't fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed
  config.assets.compile = false

  # Generate digests for assets URLs
  config.assets.digest = true

  # Precompile additional assets (application.js, application.css, and all
  # non-JS/CSS are already added)
  config.assets.precompile += ['zxcvbn.js', 'hammer.min.js', 'jquery.ba-throttle-debounce.min.js', 'mediaCheck.js', 'application-no-mq.css', 'lte-ie7.js', 'mailcheck.js', 'browserconfig.xml', 'main.css', 'oamm.js', 'oamm.min.js']
```

Here are the relevant parts from `config/application.rb`:

```
    config.assets.precompile += %w( *.js ^[^_]*.css *.css.erb )

    # Enable the asset pipeline
    config.assets.enabled = true

    config.log_level = :info

    config.assets.precompile += ['rails_admin/rails_admin.css', 'rails_admin/rails_admin.js']

    # Version of your assets, change this if you want to expire all your assets
    config.assets.version = '1.0'
```

And finally, here are the relevant parts from `config/environments/staging.rb` which is somehow working fine:

```
  # Speed up asset compilation on Heroku.
  config.assets.cache_store = :dalli_store
  config.eager_load = true

  config.stripe_livemode = false
```

Comment: I had similar symptoms (asset paths didn't contain digests in production). And it was because certain methods **won't** include the digests when called from controllers/helpers (but when called from the view, they *do* provide the digest)! This was very confusing and hard to track down. The solution for my specific problem was to replace `image_url()` with `ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path('my_image.png')`, which I found from [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65990841/image-url-gives-different-result-when-run-from-controller?noredirect=1#comment116697121_65990841)

Comment: maybe check RAILS_ENV?

Comment: Can you share the versions you had before and after? for Rails, Sprockets and Sprockets-Rails gems

Comment: I'm wondering if you have some intialization issue, rails uses the `compute_asset_path` method https://apidock.com/rails/v5.2.3/ActionView/Helpers/AssetUrlHelper/compute_asset_path that is overriden by sprockets-rails https://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails/blob/1a0cf7a4572d0ee728d3dda2013d3305a77932f1/lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb#L77, if for some reason that method is not changed you won't have the digest paths.